# como atualizar um gráfico ultilizando o método $.load()

Tags: html, jquery, d3.js

Tenho um gráfico que é criado da div do id "#chart", o problema é que tenho um modal que cadastra mais informações no gráfico e ao clicar em "voltar" quero atualiza-lo com esses novos dados através do método $.load(). Alguma ideia de como fazer isso ?

```
<html> 
 <body>
  <div id="grafico" style="width:99.5%">
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="info" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

if (window.location.hash === "") {
  d3.json("Paineis/gerencias.json", function(err, res) {
      if (!err) {
          console.log(res);
          var data = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.gerencia; }).key(function(d) { return d.key; }).entries(res);
          main({title: "Demandas em andamento"}, {key: "Total de demandas", values: data});
      }
  });
 }
```

Comment: podes por favor colocar o código que inicializas os d3.js.  Geralmente bibliotecas do género sempre tem métodos para fazer update etc...

Comment: pronto. Editei o código acima

Comment: o gráfico é um zoomable treemap

Comment: Após inserir novos dados no gráfico, tenta chamar novamente o `d3.json("Paineis/gerencias.json", function(err, res) {...`

Comment: Isso funcionou, pórem, o gráfico antigo ainda permanece na página. E se eu chamo a função " $("#chart").remove() " antes de chamar o novo json, não aparece nenhum gráfico na tela. Tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo ?